# Can we finally kill .999=1?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, closing

This has been mentioned before ([notably, here by Akhil](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/questions-that-keep-getting-bumped-back)). But [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11/does-99999-1) is tenacious indeed. For the past three(maybe four days), it has jumped up to the top. Frankly, I am tired of seeing it. I find it enormously unlikely that anything relevant is being added. Can we *please* close/lock/protect/destroy this question now? I just want it to fade away into the archives so that people can find it if they search for it, but it doesn't continue its phoenixial habits. :/

Comment: +1 for agreement.

Comment: oh ya, well +1 for agreeing with your +1! Now what!

Comment: For the record, I am hoping a moderator will reply to this question with what is going on with this. Thank you!

Comment: "Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:
 * the tag 'status-completed' is moderator-only"

Comment: @Tom I have flagged your post for mods. In another thread I was informed that the proper protocol, is not to post a comment like that, butto flag the post for moderator atttention and make the little message a comment. I was kinda excited to learn about this feature, it is very useful.

Comment: +.999... in agreement.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, I've locked the question so that no further modifications (upvotes, edits, answers) can be made and it won't float to the top. I didn't close it for some of the several reasons mentioned against closing in earlier discussions: the question isn't really off-topic and it's one lots of people studying basic math have.

Comment: Thanks! And some extra characters...