# Can we lock the question "Do complex numbers really exist?"

Tags: discussion, specific-question

In the spirit of

#### [Can we finally kill 0.999=1?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/670/can-we-finally-kill-9991),

#### *Can we finally "kill" (read: "lock") ["Do complex numbers really exist?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154/do-complex-numbers-really-exist)* ?

Comment: Actually, my wife asked me a variant of this question - saying that she can't relate to complex numbers since she can't "see" them. The thread has helped me, particularly I haven't thought about the idea of denoting it as a pair with arithmetic defined on it, and later identifying (0,1) with i. Simple, but effective.

Comment: I think if you change the title it's actually a good question. (The title is very silly though, and it is a shame that it is named so badly)

Comment: See [Can we finally kill 0.999...=1?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/670/can-we-finally-kill-9991) for the reasons to **kill** and the effective handling (by Katie Banks) of a question such as this that has very likely received all of the useful answers it possibly could - *but is still worth keeping around.*

Comment: To what extent would you be satisfied filtering out questions tagged [philosophical]?

Comment: @Kaestur: Thank you for the filtering suggestion.  I am satisfied with the outcome of the conversation thus far - I really just wanted to ask the community and enough have chimed in (or remained silent) in support of leaving this question untouched at this point.

Comment: My choice of language apparently had some unforeseen backlash :/

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199676/what-are-imaginary-numbers/201786

Answer (score 11):

Why? Some folks (including I) spent significant time to  give thoughtful replies.

Comment: So just lock it, i.e. no one can change and bump it anymore

Comment: Of course, and their efforts (and yours) are extremely useful.  The action taken on 0.999=1? was intended to preserve the replies but lock it to keep it from collecting more responses - as it is unlikely that more responses will add anything useful at this point.

Comment: Why do you think that future replies are unlikely to add anything useful? I think future members might have much of interest to say. I don't think the thread should be closed, locked, or restricted in any way.

Answer (score 8):

It could be protected, to put a 10 reputation threshold for the new answerers.  But I disagree that it needs to be locked or closed, for the moment.

Answer (score -4):

Kill it because it's poorly conceived.  In what sense do real numbers "exist" anyway?  Do ordinary people even understand what is meant by cauchy-completeness?  The ordinary examples of real nonrational numbers are still zeroes of polynomials with coefficients in Q (algebraic).  In what sense does the quantity $\pi$ "exist"?

The idea that the real numbers are a totally concrete concept is really just a misunderstanding of the facts.  In the same way that $pi$ is defined to be a solution to the pair of simultaneous equations cos(x)=-1, sin(x)=0 up to integral multiplication, $i$ is defined to be a solution to the equation $x^2+1=0$.

Comment: why downvote? I upvoted back. Sometimes such questions about mathematical meaning of something is just vague, and I agree those that holds mathematics is no more than a manipulation of rules.